# How to rebase in Jgit

Tags: java, git, git-rebase, jgit

I want to rebase master onto origin/master. I am using this code:

```
private void rebase(Git git) throws GitAPIException {
    git.checkout().setName("master").call();
    List<Ref> branches = git.branchList().setListMode(ListBranchCommand.ListMode.ALL).call();
    for (Ref ref : branches) {
        if (ref.getName().equals("refs/remotes/origin/master")) {
            git.rebase().setUpstream("refs/remotes/origin/master").call();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

After running `git status` I see `rebase in progress` and no rebase done.

Comment: `rebase().call()` returns a `RebaseResult`, inspect this result to see if the rebase command succeeded or why it didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative I tried pull with rebase

```
private void pullWithRebase(Git git) throws GitAPIException {
    git.checkout().setName("master").call();
    List<Ref> branches = git.branchList().setListMode(ListBranchCommand.ListMode.ALL).call();
    String remoteMasterBranchName = "refs/remotes/origin/master";
    for (Ref ref : branches) {
        if (remoteMasterBranchName.equals(ref.getName())) {
            git.pull().setRemoteBranchName("master").setRebase(true).call();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

At first it didn't work for me for the same reason. But the case was that I had merge conflicts. I ran this code again so that there were no conflicts and it worked.